# Express a number as a sum of powers of 2

Tags: python, performance

This is my function:

```
def two_powers(num):
    powers = []
    i = 1
    while i <= num:
        if i & num:
            powers.append(i)
        i <<= 1
    return powers
```

I have python 3.6(Windows 10 64-bit). I want the result in the form of a list. My problem statement is to express a integer(`num`) in the form of sum of powers of 2.

Do I have to create a list in the beginning and then append to it each time ? Can I return a list directly without creating it in the beginning ?

This will will speed up my execution time, right ?

Comment: What version of Python do you use and what is your actual problem statement? Why do you need a list? In what format do you want the result?

Comment: @Mast I have python 3.6. I want the result in the form of a list. My problem statement is to express a integer`(num)` in the form of sum of powers of 2.

Comment: You could probably turn it into a one-liner generator statement, which creates the list for you. But I'm not well-versed enough in those to figure out how.

Comment: @Mast Even I couldn't do it.

Comment: As a fun aside, an integer is already expressed as a sum of powers of 2, and usually you can work with that directly rather than having to make a list *at all*. So if you're worried about execution time, look at a broader context.

Comment: @harold I don't get what you mean. Can you please explain it further ?

Comment: @Agile_Eagle if you ask an other question, with context about what you use the powers of two for, then perhaps I can explain how to avoid "deconstructing" the number. But it's context dependent, I can't say how to do it in general, there is no single answer.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle It seems like not fully understand the implications of all numbers in computers being represented in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number). In particular, just like each digit of base 10 represents a power of 10 (e.g. 123 = 10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0), each digit of base 2 (binary) represents a power of 2 (e.g. 0b101 = 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0)

Comment: One important question to ask yourself is is this actually a performance bottleneck. Surely you don't want to be doing something to very negatively affects performance, but often in Python code that is more idiomatic is better than obfuscated code that performs better (unless this code is on a critical path).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably cheating, but the `bin(x)` function would do most of the heavy lifting, converting `x` into a string of bits.  Iterate in the reverse direction (via `[::-1]`) to match bits with their proper two-to-the-power-of index, select only those indices where `bit` is `"1"`, and create the list with list comprehension.  It could be done in one statement.

```
def two_powers(num):
    return [ 1 << idx for idx, bit in enumerate(bin(num)[:1:-1]) if bit == "1" ]
```

*Note*: `bin()` actually returns a string prefixed with `"0b"`.  The above code skips the prefix, by using an end index in the slice: `[:1:-1]`.

---

As @200_success mentions, creating and decimating the binary string might not be the most efficient approach.  A bit of research turned up `int.bit_length()` which can be used to determine an upper bound in the `range()` for list comprehension.  <strike>Improved</strike> solution:

```
def two_powers(num):
    return [ 1 << idx for idx in range(num.bit_length()) if num & (1 << idx) ]
```

---

Timing for the original method, Harold's, and my method, on 32 & 64 bit numbers, with most significant bit set, for various density of `1` bits:

[image]

As can be seen, and as expected, Harold's method is best when there are more zero bits than one bits.  With more one bits than zero bits, it can perform worse than the original.  The list comprehension method is always slightly better than the original, but not by a lot.

The real surprise is the `bin(num)` version, which converts the number to a string.  I threw that into my timing for a laugh, and it turned out to be *way better* than my *improved* version.  Moral of the story: "Test it! Don't guess."

Comment: That involves creating a string. Is it actually faster than a loop that just does arithmetic?

Comment: @200_success I can’t claim it will be faster.  In fact, I haven’t even run the code; I just typed it in on my phone.  However, it does address the questions: “_Do I have to create a list in the beginning and then append to it each time?  Can I return a list directly without creating it in the beginning?_”

Comment: @AJNeufeld, harold's solution is faster, I checked it using `timeit`

Comment: Harold's solution is faster only for some numbers "_(depending on the size and sparseness of the input)_".  When testing 31-bit numbers (0x4#######) with 24 or more 1-bits, my solution is faster; with 23 or less 1-bits, Harold's is faster.

Comment: @200_success Apparently, the "creating a string" method can actually be faster.

Answer (score 5):

List building performance aside, there is a way to get the powers of two out without touching the bits in between, by using the formulas:

```
isolateLowestSetBit(x) = x & -x
resetLowestSetBit(x) = x & (x - 1)
```

These have been explained elsewhere.

Using those definitions, you can extract the powers of two like this:

```
def two_powers(num):
    powers = []
    while num != 0:
        powers.append(num & -num)
        num = num & (num - 1)
    return powers
```

Since it potentially avoids testing many bits (depending on the size and sparseness of the input) it may be faster. It can also work out not so well, for very dense numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I think that list generator won't improve your performance in this case because it will require you to create another list (since `range` is not a good fit for this). You could create a generator that `yield`s powers but it basically will be moving one piece of code to another function

So I don't think you can optimize this. Unless you allocate memory for a list before filling it but it won't improve readability.

IMHO

UPD. maybe this will be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

Comment: Readability is not an issue. Can you please show me how I can "allocate memory for a list before filling it"

Comment: It depends on context. If you know boundaries for num you could just allocate `result = maxSize * [None]` and fill it. It will be significantly faster than `.append`ing. 
Maybe you should take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't really know python. I used it like 5 years ago when studied at school